# Implementing a page from psd proportionally

Tags: html, css, psd

When I get a psd(1750*2400),I found the images and font size were too big for lower resolution.Is it possible to make page fit in different resolution ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I usually divide this into 2. What I mean is that the dimension of the website, in this situation, is 875x1200. Thus for every spec, such as fonts, block width, image width should be divided into 2.

For example, the Header font size is 42px then you could apply 21px.

Comment: couldn't understand properly why to divide. please provide more description.

Comment: this means the psd is 2 times the real website layout

Comment: so whatever the real size then I've to divide by 2.

Comment: That's true. I always apply this with my phone layout design since the designer team design template 2 times bigger than the actual size of mobile device

Comment: but my designers asks for same font size applied in psd.

Comment: Yes, but in such situation the psd is ready to be implemented, this is a way to implement

Answer (score 0):

For images you can do this purely with CSS by specifying the width and height of your preference. The browser will resize the image (though if you don't choose the right aspect-ratio the image may look obviously expanded or compressed).

```
img {
 height: 300px; //whatever height you want
 width: 200px //whatever width you want
}
```

For a responsive layout you can use CSS3 media queries to achieve the best look on different resolutions.

Example for responsive layouts:

```
img {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%
}

@media screen and (max-width:64em) {
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%
}
```

As for the font-size, you may have to sacrifice pixel-perfection at times for the best look and decide for yourself whether the font looks appropriate for the display or not.

This too can be controlled by using media queries though:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 32em) {
  font-size: 1.5em
}
```